# Printing on macosx: what's best way to print a nstableview

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsview, nsprintoperation

I'm having an issue printing from my desktop application on macosx.
I built a view in my IB file that I use for printing. 
Then a call my action that throu

```
printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self.myPrintView printInfo: printInfo];
```

print the `NSView`.

Just before that I use a simple function

```
[self displayPrintingData];
```

to build up my data on the view

```
-(void)displayPrintingData {

   //header
   self.headerData.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   self.headerData.string = @"bla bla bla";
   self.footerData.string = @"ribla ribla ribla";

   [self.printTableView reloadData];
}
```

My problem is that I need to print as many line as I inserted (using different nsview and different nstableview).
How can I reach the goal to shorten or lengthen my NSTableView? Is this the best way to print dynamically multiple lines?

thanks in advance for your suggestions!!!!!

cheers

Comment: The table view is automatically resized. Make the enclosing scroll view as big as possible on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you said...you meant tableview's scrollview? it is not enclosed but is viceversa: scrollview encloses tableview... How can I predict max number of rows? how can I predict how many pages I need to print? it depends... Can you explain a little bit better?

Comment: You didn't mention multiple pages. Did you read [Printing Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083-SW1)?

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't help me... I thought it was implicit in the fact that I need to render a tableview with an undefined number of lines... How can you guess how many lines the user will insert??? can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self.printTableView];
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = printOperation.printInfo;
[printInfo.dictionary setObject:@YES forKey:NSPrintHeaderAndFooter];
[printOperation runOperation];
```

Note: the view is the tableview. This is a subclass of NSTableView with methods:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pageHeader
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"bla bla bla"];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)pageFooter
{
    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ribla ribla ribla"];
}
```

Comment: Thia is really halpfull!!!! Thanks a lot... Just another question: in case a have to print two NSTableView? how would you set up the view?

Comment: Can't you put the data in one tableview? If you want to print multiple views, put them in a superview and print this superview. Make the scrollview just big enough to fit the tableview without scrolling or white space.

Comment: ..on modern macOS versions this approach raises an 'not legal to call -layoutSubtreeIfNeeded' exception :-/

Comment: @ATV apparently `NSTableView` has changed and this isn't the best way to print a table view anymore. Which version is "modern macOS versions"?

Comment: @Willeke 10.14, 10.15, 11, 12...

Comment: @ATV I don't see any issues on 10.15. If you want help printing your table view then ask a new question please.

Comment: @Willeke Crops and missing page breaks everywhere.. basically unusable.
Probably worth create a new topic, agreed